# Parsing a file that looks like JSON to a JSON

Tags: python, json, string, parsing

I'm trying to figure out was is the best way to go about this problem:
I'm reading text lines from a certain buffer that eventually creates a certain log that looks something like this:

```
Some_Information: here there's some information about date and hour
Additional information: log summary #1234:
details {
  name: "John Doe"
  address: "myAdress"
  phone: 01234567
}

information {
  age: 30
  height: 1.70
  weight: 70
}
```

I would like to get all the fields in this log to a dictionary which I can later turn into a json file, the different sections in the log are not important so for example if myDictionary is a dictionary variable in python I would like to have:

```
> myDictionary['age']
```

will show me `30`.

and the same for all other fields.

Speed is very important here that's why I would like to just go through every line once and get it in a dictionary

My way about doing this would be to for each line that contains ":" colon I would split the string and get the key and the value in the dictionary.
is there a better way to do it?
Is there any python module that would be sufficient?

If more information is needed please let me know.

Edit:
So I've tried something that to me look to work best so far,
I am currently reading from a file to simulate the reading of the buffer

My code:

```
import json
import shlex

newDict = dict()

with open('log.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    try:
        line = line.replace(" ", "")
        stringSplit = line.split(':')
        key = stringSplit[0]
        value = stringSplit[1]
        value = shlex.split(value)
        newDict[key] = value[0]
    except:
        continue
with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
   json.dump(newDict, fp)
```

Resulting in the following .json:

```json
{"name": "JohnDoe", "weight": "70", "Additionalinformation": "logsummary#1234",
 "height": "1.70", "phone": "01234567", "address": "myAdress", "age": "30"}
```

Comment: Can you get the process that fills the buffer/log to generate actual, syntactically correct JSON? Then you can use the [`json` module of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/library/json.html) to parse, manipulate and output (again as JSON) it.

Comment: No, the module that creates this log sits in a process I don't have access to, I can just view the text.

Comment: Fun fact: If you just replace `{` by `:` and `}` by an empty string in your example, you get valid (and meaningfully structured) [YAML](http://yaml.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't described exactly what the desired output should be from the sample input, so it's not completely clear what you want done. So I guessed and the following only extracts data values from lines following one that contains a `'{'` until one with a `'}'` in it is encountered, while ignoring others.

It uses the `re` module to isolate the two parts of each dictionary item definition found on the line, and then uses the `ast` module to convert the value portion of that into a valid Python literal (i.e. string, number, tuple, list, dict, bool, and `None`).

```
import ast
import json
import re

pat = re.compile(r"""(?P<key>\w+)\s*:\s*(?P<value>.+)$""")

data_dict = {}
with open('log.txt', 'rU') as f:
    braces = 0
    for line in (line.strip() for line in f):
        if braces > 0:
            match = pat.search(line)
            if match and len(match.groups()) == 2:
                key = match.group('key')
                value = ast.literal_eval(match.group('value'))
                data_dict[key] = value
        elif '{' in line:
            braces += 1
        elif '}' in line:
            braces -= 1
        else:
            pass  # ignore line

print(json.dumps(data_dict, indent=4))
```

Output from your example input:

```
{                        
    "name": "John Doe",  
    "weight": 70,        
    "age": 30,           
    "height": 1.7,       
    "phone": 342391,     
    "address": "myAdress"
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! is the ast.literal_eval operation wasteful in terms of run time?

Comment: Wasteful as compared to what, parsing it yourself? I think essentially it's the same code that's used in the process of converting Python scripts into interpreter byte-code — so is very likely to be highly optimized. Beware of premature optimization, ["the root of all evil"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).